# JavaMail API on Android

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to send an email on Android using the JavaMail API, it's just a simple test

But whenever I try to launch the app, this exception pops up

```
2020-09-23 13:23:42.442 21860-21971/ae.ucg.mailtest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-2
    Process: ae.ucg.mailtest, PID: 21860
    java.lang.VerifyError: Rejecting class com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain that attempts to sub-type erroneous class com.sun.mail.handlers.handler_base (declaration of 'com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain' appears in /data/app/~~nyiEJPyVs6-ADHqg-ebklA==/ae.ucg.mailtest-_Q4dGJfXP_9F5CZNfhDVtQ==/base.apk)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap.getDataContentHandler(MailcapCommandMap.java:601)
        at javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap.createDataContentHandler(MailcapCommandMap.java:555)
        at javax.activation.DataHandler.getDataContentHandler(DataHandler.java:597)
        at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:299)
        at javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility.getEncoding(MimeUtility.java:316)
        at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:1551)
        at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.updateHeaders(MimeMessage.java:2238)
        at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.saveChanges(MimeMessage.java:2198)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:99)
        at ae.ucg.mailtest.MainActivity$onCreate$1.invokeSuspend(MainActivity.kt:38)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:56)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:738)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
     Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.sun.mail.handlers.handler_base: java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[] com.sun.mail.handlers.handler_base.getTransferDataFlavors() failed to verify: java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[] com.sun.mail.handlers.handler_base.getTransferDataFlavors(): [0x4]  can't resolve returned type 'Unresolved Reference: java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[]' or 'Reference: javax.activation.ActivationDataFlavor[]' (declaration of 'com.sun.mail.handlers.handler_base' appears in /data/app/~~nyiEJPyVs6-ADHqg-ebklA==/ae.ucg.mailtest-_Q4dGJfXP_9F5CZNfhDVtQ==/base.apk)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap.getDataContentHandler(MailcapCommandMap.java:601) 
        at javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap.createDataContentHandler(MailcapCommandMap.java:555) 
        at javax.activation.DataHandler.getDataContentHandler(DataHandler.java:597) 
        at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:299) 
        at javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility.getEncoding(MimeUtility.java:316) 
        at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:1551) 
        at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.updateHeaders(MimeMessage.java:2238) 
        at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.saveChanges(MimeMessage.java:2198) 
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:99) 
        at ae.ucg.mailtest.MainActivity$onCreate$1.invokeSuspend(MainActivity.kt:38) 
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33) 
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:56) 
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571) 
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:738) 
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678) 
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
```

I'm aware something is wrong in the library itself, but what exactly am I supposed to do?

This is my code

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                val props = Properties().apply {
                    this["mail.smtp.host"] = "smtp.gmail.com"
                    this["mail.smtp.socketFactory.port"] = "465"
                    this["mail.smtp.socketFactory.class"] = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"
                    this["mail.smtp.auth"] = "true"
                    this["mail.smtp.port"] = "465"
                }

                val session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, object : Authenticator() {
                    override fun getPasswordAuthentication() = PasswordAuthentication(Config.EMAIL, Config.PASSWORD)
                })

                val message = MimeMessage(session).apply {
                    setFrom(InternetAddress(Config.EMAIL))
                    addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress("..."))
                    subject = "Hello world"
                    setText("This is a hello world message", "UTF-8")
                }
                Transport.send(message)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is the library I'm using

```
implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.6.5'
implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.6.5'
```

Comment: Does the JAF pom.xml have [invalid compiler arguments for -Xlint](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaf/pull/55/commits/a8c2ddbd96ae3a9afc3b2de2a0c6bf0c7aa6be1f)?

Comment: @jmehrens I'm not working on a Java project, I'm working on Android. So I don't have a pom.xml file in my project.
Unless I actually have to add one

Comment: That link above is related to [Android compilation failure due to possible badly formed compiler args in pom.xml](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaf/issues/53) which looked like your issue.  My thought was you should try older versions of JAF/JavaMail to see if this problem persists.

Comment: What version of Android are you running this on?  Pre Android 11 this all worked fine but now on Android 11 I am receiving the same error.

Comment: Yes on Android 11 emulator, I guess it's a new issue from Android itself

Comment: I've reported this as a bug to Google.  Here is the link https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172544275   Go ahead to the link and star the issue - that will let Google know you are affected by it and hopefully it will be address faster.

Comment: it's still broken...

Comment: try out javax mail:https://code.google.com/archive/p/javamail-android/downloads It work perfect on every device.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66673164/12596713 here is a code in this question of javax mail

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, this bug is only on SDK level 30 (Android 11), but [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172544275#comment23) I found a solution:

In your `app/build.gradle` file you need to

1. Upgrade to newer version of the mail API (at least 1.6.6):

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.6.6'
    implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.6.6'
    ...
}
```

2. exclude these files in packagingOptions:

```
android {
    ...
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.md'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.md'
        }
    }
}
```

[source](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172544275#comment23)

Using Gradle Kotlin DSL with Version Catalog:

`app/build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
android {
    ...
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += listOf("META-INF/NOTICE.md", "META-INF/LICENSE.md")
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(libs.jakarta.mail)
    implementation(libs.jakarta.mail.activation)
    ...
}
```

`gradle/libs.versions.toml`

```ini
[versions]
jakarta-mail = "1.6.6"
...

[libraries]
jakarta-mail = { module = "com.sun.mail:android-mail", version.ref = "jakarta-mail" }
jakarta-mail-activation = { module = "com.sun.mail:android-activation", version.ref = "jakarta-mail" }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and there were a couple of things to note in order to resolve it:

1. As other's ([radda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68563365/2041005), and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68563266/2041005)) have mentioned, there's a [Google Issue Tracker Issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172544275) that covers and provides why this issue is happening:

> API level 30 adds a new (verifier) feature that verifies that all referenced code actually exists - or fails a build.

2. Even in fixing the issue - by referencing and ensuring you're providing the referenced code *(by, for instance, updating the dependencies to the latest - which at this time are [1.6.7](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.sun.mail/android-mail/1.6.7/jar))*; you'll find a build still throws a relatively straight forward complaint:

[image: Bad Files Found Error]

To resolve (and get up-to-date):

1. If you were providing the libraries manually via `/app/libs/mail.jar`, `/app/libs/activation.jar`, and `/app/libs/additionnal.jar` - you can go ahead and remove them; both `google()` and `maven()` repositories are enabled in Android projects - so simply add;

*to your project-level gradle file (`/build.gradle`):*

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        // ...
        java_mail_version = "1.6.7"
    }
    // ...
}

// ...
```

*to your app/module-level gradle file (`/app/build.gradle`):*

```
    //...
dependencies {
    // ...

    // Dumb Email Sending
    implementation "com.sun.mail:android-mail:$java_mail_version"

    // REMOVE THESE - DEPS WILL DOWNLOAD AUTOMATICALLY
    //implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.6.7' // from 1.6.4
    //implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-additionnal:1.6.7' // from 1.6.4
}

// ...
```

...and with that you'll have resolved the *'latest version(s)'* issue once and for all *(including where to find them)*.

To resolve issue #2, add;

*to that same app/module-level gradle file (`/app/build.gradle`):*

```
// ...
android {
    // ...
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
            excludes += '/META-INF/{NOTICE.md,LICENSE.md}' // <-- This line
        }
    }
}

// ...
```

That resolved it for me, and I'm happy not to have to manually lug around the `.jar` files anymore:

[image: Build Successful]

[image: Email(s) Successfully Sent]