# VerifyError rejecting class text_plain from JavaMail API

Tags: java, android, email, jakarta-mail, verifyerror

I'm developing an application that allows the user to contact me by sending an email (the user only inputs the message, sender and receiver emails are both mine). I'm trying to implement this with gmail using the JavaMail API. However, I keep getting this error at the `Transport.send(mimeMessage)` line.

Here are the error messages:

> Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Rejecting class com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain that attempts to sub-type erroneous class com.sun.mail.handlers.handler_base (declaration of 'com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain' appears in /data/app/~~T_TRkO9R_v9j4iEdr4K9Yg==/com.example.compusec-dPeAL8DtGJvU45dJpt8xxA==/base.apk)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.sun.mail.handlers.handler_base: java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[] com.sun.mail.handlers.handler_base.getTransferDataFlavors() failed to verify: java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[] com.sun.mail.handlers.handler_base.getTransferDataFlavors(): [0x4]  can't resolve returned type 'Unresolved Reference: java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[]' or 'Reference: javax.activation.ActivationDataFlavor[]' (declaration of 'com.sun.mail.handlers.handler_base' appears in /data/app/~~T_TRkO9R_v9j4iEdr4K9Yg==/com.example.compusec-dPeAL8DtGJvU45dJpt8xxA==/base.apk)

Here is my code:

```java
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

    session = javax.mail.Session.getInstance(properties, new javax.mail.Authenticator(){
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication(){
            return new PasswordAuthentication("sender@gmail.com","senderpass");
        }
    });

    session.setDebug(true);

    MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
    try {
        mimeMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress("sender@gmail.com"));
        mimeMessage.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, String.valueOf(new InternetAddress(email)));
        mimeMessage.setSubject(subject);
        mimeMessage.setText(message);
        Transport.send(mimeMessage);
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

And the gradle script:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt' // picks the JavaMail license file
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.java.net/content/groups/public/"
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    compile 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.6.2'
    compile 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.6.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Comment: I've reported this as a bug to Google.  Here is the link https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172544275   Go ahead to the link and star the issue - that will let Google know you are affected by it and hopefully it will be address faster.

Comment: @gbotha Starred. Hope it's resolved soon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am having the same issue.  What I can tell you is that if you target Android 10 and lower (SDK 29 or lower) it works fine.  I have been using it for years.  However, as soon as I target Android 11 (SDK 30) then I get this error.  My guess is com.sun.mail dependencies need to be updated.  I'm using the latest 1.6.5 and still doesn't work.  So I suggest targeting SDK 29 for now and see if that helps.

Comment: Fortunately I'm targeting Android 10 and lowering the SDK to 29 worked perfectly! Thank you very much :)

Comment: I submitted an Android bug 2 days ago and been conversing with Google.  They say it is expected behavior for Android 11 and something needs to be modified with our code, but they're not too clear on what to do yet. You can see the bug issue submitted here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172544275 and star it to show you're affected, and also add your own comments.

Comment: I can also confirm that lowering to 29 is working.

Answer (score 14):

In your `app/build.gradle` file you need to

1. Upgrade to newer version of the mail API (at least 1.6.6):

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.6.6'
    implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.6.6'
    ...
}
```

2. exclude these files in packagingOptions:

```
android {
    ...
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.md'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.md'
        }
    }
}
```

[source](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172544275#comment23)

Using Gradle Kotlin DSL with Version Catalog:

`app/build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
android {
    ...
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += listOf("META-INF/NOTICE.md", "META-INF/LICENSE.md")
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(libs.jakarta.mail)
    implementation(libs.jakarta.mail.activation)
    ...
}
```

`gradle/libs.versions.toml`

```ini
[versions]
jakarta-mail = "1.6.6"
...

[libraries]
jakarta-mail = { module = "com.sun.mail:android-mail", version.ref = "jakarta-mail" }
jakarta-mail-activation = { module = "com.sun.mail:android-activation", version.ref = "jakarta-mail" }
...
```

Answer (score 2):

My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72038558/2041005), that is in-line with other answers (as that answer explains), does provide a solution (I'll skip to the content here, details can be read there);

The issue:

> API level 30 adds a new (verifier) feature that verifies that all referenced code actually exists - or fails a build.

To resolve:

1. If you were providing the libraries manually via `/app/libs/mail.jar`, `/app/libs/activation.jar`, and `/app/libs/additionnal.jar` - you can go ahead and remove them; both `google()` and `maven()` repositories are enabled in Android projects, and the latest deps are available there. They include new META-INF files, so we'll also need to remove them from the build when we update the deps;

*to your project-level gradle file (`/build.gradle`):*

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        // ...
        java_mail_version = "1.6.7"
    }
    // ...
}

// ...
```

*to your app/module-level gradle file (`/app/build.gradle`):*

```
    //...
android {
    // ...
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
            excludes += '/META-INF/{NOTICE.md,LICENSE.md}' // <-- This line
        }
    }
}
    // ...
dependencies {
    // ...

    // Dumb Email Sending
    implementation "com.sun.mail:android-mail:$java_mail_version"

    // REMOVE THESE - DEPS WILL DOWNLOAD AUTOMATICALLY
    //implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.6.7' // from 1.6.4
    //implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-additionnal:1.6.7' // from 1.6.4
}

// ...
```

That's it, issue resolved on API Level 30 - and no more lugging the `.jar` files around (if you were).